# How can some executable automatically run as root

Tags: filesystems, security

Why some executable as being launched, it's automatically run as root by requiring user to put in password (by its ls -l info below) ?

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 975856 Feb  9 13:02 <filename>
```

while other executable of such the exact same file info except file size and time, will not automatically run as root by not requiring user to put in password

How is its uncommon file setting/attribute?

Comment: Since there is no readline init file used by zsh, there is no equivalent. What is it that you want to **achieve** by doing this?

Comment: Are you describing something you have observed or something you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand the question correctly, you want to know why only some scripts prompt the user for a password and what this has to do with the information listed by the 'ls' command.)

The `ls` command provides information (for each file in the directory specified) about file attributes, such as read permissions, write permissions and user/group ownership.

In your case, `ls` reports that `<filename>` is owned by the 'root' user (1st occurrence of 'root' in `ls` output) and 'root' group (2nd occurrence of 'root' in `ls` output). This means that user permissions apply to user 'root' and group permissions apply to the group 'root'.

The read/write/execute permissions are represented in these 10 chaarcters: `-rwxr-xr-x`.

1. First we have the Unix file type (`-`), which is '-' for a regular file, 'd' for a directory and 's' for a symbolic link.
2. Next: `rwx` , which are the user permissions. User 'root' (the owner of the file) is given read, write and execute permissions.
3. Next: `r-x` , which are the group permissions. All users in group 'root' (the group owner of the file) are given read and execute permissions.
4. Next: `r-x` (again), which are the permissions for other users. All other users are given read and execute permissions. (Note that execute permissions only determine whether you can treat the file as an executable or not; all commands and system calls performed inside that executable are still subject to being denied execution due to insufficient privileges.)

See [File-system permissions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions) for a more thorough explanation.

Note that `ls` does not tell you anything about the behavior of the executable; it cannot know whether the executable will attempt to format your disk (thus requiring root privileges) or whether it's just a "Hello, world!" script. You could have a disk-formatting script owned by an unprivileged user, but the script would fail unless run by root; you could have a script which does nothing but that doesn't have execute permissions for root, so root wouldn't be able to run it. (Note that root can change any permissions and ownerships, so it can just override that.)

Here's a simple bash script which checks if it's running as root and, if not, attempts to use sudo to gain root privileges. If you copy/paste into a text editor and save the file, it should be owned by an unprivileged user, but note that:

1. the script's *behavior* allows it to potentially execute root-only
   commands, but *only if* sudo succeeds;
2. the above has no relationship whatsoever with the output of `ls`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

### test_root.sh
# small script to experiment with detecting root and running as sudo

# print some file attributes
LS_RESULT=$(ls -alh $0)
echo "ls information for ${0}:"
echo -e "${LS_RESULT}\n"

# check effective user id and attempt to rerun script if not root
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then 
  echo "Not running as root!"
  echo "Attempt to rerun with sudo? (y/N)"
  
  read -n1 "ANSWER" # read a y/n character
  if [ "$ANSWER" == "y" ] || [ "$ANSWER" == "Y" ]; then
    PROG_NAME=$(readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}) # get proper path to this script
    COMMAND="sudo ${PROG_NAME} ${@}"
    
    echo -e "\n$COMMAND\n\n" 
    bash -c "$COMMAND" # rerun script as sudo
  else
    echo -e "\nExiting ..."
  fi
else
  echo "Hello, root!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 2 chmod` and you'll find:

```
The new file mode is specified in mode, which is a bit mask created by ORing together zero or more of the following:

   S_ISUID  (04000)
      set-user-ID (set process effective user ID on execve(2))
    S_ISGID  (02000)
      set-group-ID (set process effective group ID on execve(2);
      mandatory locking, as described in fcntl(2); take a new
      file's group from parent directory, as described in
      chown(2) and mkdir(2))
    ...
```

Read `man chmod` on "`SETUID AND SETGID BITS`".

This is the old method, and has been superseded by "capabilities". Read `man -k capability`.

Comment: Read the question. This isn’t about suid executables.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is nothing to do with the file permissions. The program requesting the root password must be doing something along the lines of....

```
if whoami != root 
   su root argv(0)
```